# Pagination with DynamoDBMapper Java AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

From the API docs dynamo db does support pagination for scan and query operations. The catch here is to set the `ExclusiveStartIndex` of current request to the value of the `LastEvaluatedIndex` of previous request to get next set (logical page) of results.

I'm trying to implement the same but I'm using `DynamoDBMapper`, which seems to have lot more advantages like tight coupling with data models.  So if I wanted to do the above, I'm assuming I would do something like below:

```java
// Mapping of hashkey of the last item in previous query operation
Map<String, AttributeValue> lastHashKey = .. 
DynamoDBQueryExpression expression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression();

...
expression.setExclusiveStartKey();
List<Table> nextPageResults = mapper.query(Table.class, expression);
```

I hope my above understanding is correct on paginating using DynamoDBMapper. 
Secondly, how would I know that I've reached the end of results. From the docs if I use the following api:

```java
QueryResult result = dynamoDBClient.query((QueryRequest) request);
boolean isEndOfResults = StringUtils.isEmpty(result.getLastEvaluatedKey());
```

Coming back to using DynamoDBMapper, how can I know if I've reached end of results in this case.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You have a couple different options with the [`DynamoDBMapper`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html), depending on which way you want go.

- [`query`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#query(java.lang.Class,%20com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBQueryExpression)) - returns a [`PaginatedQueryList`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/PaginatedQueryList.html)
- [`queryPage`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#queryPage(java.lang.Class,%20com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBQueryExpression)) - returns a [`QueryResultPage`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/QueryResultPage.html)
- [`scan`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#scan(java.lang.Class,%20com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBScanExpression)) - returns a [`PaginatedScanList`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/PaginatedScanList.html)
- [`scanPage`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#scanPage(java.lang.Class,%20com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBScanExpression)) - returns a [`ScanResultPage`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/ScanResultPage.html)

The part here is understanding the difference between the methods, and what functionality their returned objects encapsulate.

I'll go over `PaginatedScanList` and `ScanResultPage`, but these methods/objects basically mirror each other.

The `PaginatedScanList` says the following, emphasis mine:

> Implementation of the List interface that represents the results from a scan in AWS DynamoDB. **Paginated results are loaded on demand when the user executes an operation that requires them.** Some operations, such as size(), must fetch the entire list, but results are lazily fetched page by page when possible.

This says that results are loaded as you iterate through the list. When you get through the first page, the second page is automatically fetched with out you having to explicitly make another request. Lazy loading the results is the default method, but it can be overridden if you call the overloaded methods and supply a `DynamoDBMapperConfig` with a different [`DynamoDBMapperConfig.PaginationLoadingStrategy`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.PaginationLoadingStrategy.html).

This is different from the `ScanResultPage`. You are given a page of results, and it is up to you to deal with the pagination yourself.

Here is quick code sample showing an example usage of both methods that I ran with a table of 5 items using DynamoDBLocal:

```java
final DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);

// Using 'PaginatedScanList'
final DynamoDBScanExpression paginatedScanListExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
        .withLimit(limit);
final PaginatedScanList<MyClass> paginatedList = mapper.scan(MyClass.class, paginatedScanListExpression);
paginatedList.forEach(System.out::println);

System.out.println();
// using 'ScanResultPage'
final DynamoDBScanExpression scanPageExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
        .withLimit(limit);
do {
    ScanResultPage<MyClass> scanPage = mapper.scanPage(MyClass.class, scanPageExpression);
    scanPage.getResults().forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("LastEvaluatedKey=" + scanPage.getLastEvaluatedKey());
    scanPageExpression.setExclusiveStartKey(scanPage.getLastEvaluatedKey());

} while (scanPageExpression.getExclusiveStartKey() != null);
```

And the output:

```
MyClass{hash=2}
MyClass{hash=1}
MyClass{hash=3}
MyClass{hash=0}
MyClass{hash=4}

MyClass{hash=2}
MyClass{hash=1}
LastEvaluatedKey={hash={N: 1,}}
MyClass{hash=3}
MyClass{hash=0}
LastEvaluatedKey={hash={N: 0,}}
MyClass{hash=4}
LastEvaluatedKey=null
```

Comment: If `limit` is set to say 2 when using `query`, it is still returning all the records. Why is it like that?

Comment: @user7 It only appears that it is returning all the records, when in fact the underlying implementation (`PaginatedQueryList`) is handling the pagination for you. Look at the documentation for [`PaginatedQueryList`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/PaginatedQueryList.html). It behaves in the same way as I posted about `scan` above. Basically, if you iterate over it, it will eventually fetch all the elements because it is automatically doing the pagination calls.

Comment: So `withLimit` does not apply for it?

Comment: From what I've read when performing a scan limit is not referring to a number of results, but the allowed throughput.

Comment: The PaginatedQueryList makes multiple calls to fetch complete set of items. The limit is used to specify the number of items to get per request.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String tableName = "tableName";
    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);
    ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec();
    scanSpec.withMaxResultSize(pageSize);
    long itemCount = table.describe().getItemCount();
    int count = 0;
    ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> items = table.scan(scanSpec);
    
    Map<String, AttributeValue> lastEvaluatedKey = null;

    do {
        Iterator<Page<Item, ScanOutcome>> iterator = items.pages().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Page<Item, ScanOutcome> page = iterator.next();
            count += page.size();
            for (Item item : page) {
                // do something with the item
            }
        }

        ScanResult scanResult = items.getLastLowLevelResult().getScanResult();
        lastEvaluatedKey = scanResult.getLastEvaluatedKey();
        if (lastEvaluatedKey != null) {
            KeyAttribute keyAttribute = new KeyAttribute("id", 
            lastEvaluatedKey.get("id").getS());
            scanSpec.withExclusiveStartKey(keyAttribute);

            if (count < itemCount) {
                items = table.scan(scanSpec);
            }
        }
    } while (count < itemCount);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).