# AWS DynamoDbMapper FilterExpression pagination in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamoDb table, the table has couple of columns,
My **Primary partition key is - pageId (String)**,
I also have a **GSI - pageContainer(String)**.

I am using DynamoDBMapper to query/scan my table,
I am trying to achieve **pagination in DynamoDb**,
I understnd paganation in DynamoDB works on **ExclusiveStartKey and LastEvaluatedKey.**

ExclusiveStartKey will be null on the 1st page query/scan,
After querying/scanning the 1st page, DynamoDB will return the LastEvaluatedKey.

If the query result is more than 1Mb or if one has put a limit for the query/scan,
**The LastEvaluatedKey's value, is then used as ExclusiveStartKey to query/scan the 2nd page and so on**.

My operation requires a **Filter Expression beginsWith**, on **pageContainer column**,
as I am trying to get data that beginsWith a certain word, it's like a "Like" condition is compared to relational db.
**I have 10 values in the table all start with "Test_test" in the pageContainer column.**

**Here's my code -**

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(DYNAMO_DB_ENDPOINT, DYNAMO_DB_REGION))
                .build();
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);

String beginWith = "Test_test";
HashMap<String, AttributeValue> filterMap = new HashMap<>();
        filterMap.put(":beginWith", new AttributeValue().withS(beginWith));

DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();   

scanExpression.withFilterExpression("begins_with(pageContainer,:beginWith)")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(filterMap)
                .withExclusiveStartKey(null)
                .withLimit(4);

ScanResultPage<PageModel> scanPage = mapper.scanPage(PageModel.class, scanExpression);
List<PageModel> pageCmsDomains = scanPage.getResults();

Map<String, AttributeValue> lastEvaluatedKey = scanPage.getLastEvaluatedKey();
System.out.println("LastEvaluatedKey=" + scanPage.getLastEvaluatedKey());
```

**Problem -**
 
The scan operation is returning me the LastEvaluatedKey but, 
nothing is coming in results(empty response).

**I am referring the following resources -**
1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.QueryScanExample.html
2. [Pagination with DynamoDBMapper Java AWS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788959/pagination-with-dynamodbmapper-java-aws-sdk)

Comment: did you check my answer? did it work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are facing is related to how filter and limit work at DynamoDB.

In DynamoDB the **limit** seems to be a kind of service protection limiting the amount of records fetched in a single operation, after the data is fetched the **filter** is applied.

For instance you are using:

```
scanExpression.withFilterExpression("begins_with(pageContainer,:beginWith)")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(filterMap)
                .withExclusiveStartKey(null)
                .withLimit(4);
```

DynamoDB starts fetching the first 4 records, if the records do not match the filter expression, they are removed from response, returning 0 records.

I would say that if you are using filter, you're probably doing something wrong, you'd better create another index and use key filtering.

From AWS DynamoDB Documentation - [Working with Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html)

> **Limiting the Number of Items in the Result Set**
>
> The Query operation allows you to limit the number of items that it
>   returns in the result. To do this, set the Limit parameter to the
>   maximum number of items that you want.
>
> For example, suppose you Query a table, with a Limit value of 6, and
>   without a filter expression. The Query result will contain the first
>   six items from the table that match the key condition expression from
>   the request.
>
> Now suppose you add a filter expression to the Query. In this case,
>   DynamoDB will apply the filter expression to the six items that were
>   returned, discarding those that do not match. The final Query result
>   will contain 6 items or fewer, depending on the number of items that
>   were filtered.